# android missed call notifications not going

Tags: notifications, missed-calls, samsung-galaxy-music-duos

I have a *Samsung Galaxy S6012.* Long time back (I do not remember when) I've got a call. Even though I answered that call, it was put as missed call. Since then it shows a missed call alert in my phone.

First I removed that particular number from the list. Still the same alert was there. Then I removed the entire log history – still the same missed call alert. I have restarted the device many times but all my work went in vain.

**NOTE** By "missed call alert" I mean a numeric ① being displayed on top of the phone icon:

[image: Missed call]

This is the phone I have http://mobile.cdn.softpedia.com/phone-pics/Samsung-Galaxy-Music-Duos-0.jpg The phone icon is at the bottom left side.If any missed calls then I get a number(like 1,2) at the top like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOfXd.png

Comment: a number on the phone icon? are you using a custom launcher, or an app for that?

Comment: @geffchang the default phone icon,I do not use any app or custom launcher

Comment: @geffchang see this http://img.podnova.com/icons_avideo/124/848/848552.jpg I am getting similar type means a phone icon like this http://cesaualberta.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/phone-icon.jpg and a number 1 which is placed at the top like the other picture

Comment: @Izzy not exactly the same icon,So rollback the question

Comment: You can [edit] your question yourself anytime, it's yours – so my apologies if you didn't want the image integrated, and no hard feelings if you revert this. Alternatively, you could also add a note there that it's something *like* this (and not exactly this). I'm pretty sure, even though not the *exact* same image, it helps people visualize the facts immediately – as opposed to reading the text multiple times and trying to imagine. So I would keep it, and optionally comment on it.

Comment: @Izzy ok then I will follow your way.I will not edit the question.Thanks

Comment: Why is there an SMS icon with an unread count in the question?

Comment: @Archer I gave this is an example.Like the image shown(numeric 2 shows 2 unread messages) In my phone icon numeric 1 is shown always